# boost compiliation of libraries?

Tags: boost

yo it has almost past about like 11 hours since i started a bjam.exe -complete as someone told me on phone. how long do it do i need to wait?

I looked up here in 'lib' thing D:\boost_1_42_0\boost_1_42_0\stage\lib

said Size is 1.78 GB and has 314 files. 15+ for whoever tells me a close number tp total files.

Comment: yo this depends on the slow processor and amount of RAM.

Comment: "How long do you need to wait" for what?  What are you expecting to see?  If you could add a more detailed description involving 1) what you want to do, 2) what you are currently experiencing and 3) what you think you expect to see, you will probably get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete rebuild on slow HDD & CPU might take that long. That is ok as long as you see that it is doing something.

You might needed to limit it to release or dubug with 1 linking settings. This will make it like 20 times faster.